# How to handle Doctrine2 entities defined in composer dependencies

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm thinking what is the best way of including entities defined inside composer dependencies in my project.

Since I want to use Doctrine CLI tool to create and keep entities in sync with database table schema I need to register their mappings. Then I can call:

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema:create
```

which is all right. Then I want to generate entities:

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-entities ./src
```

but this generates also entities for dependencies that registered their entity mappings so I end up with:

```
./src/MyPoject/Entity
./src/ProjectDependency/Entity
```

which might be a problem because `./src/ProjectDependency/Entity` redeclares classes that are already defined somewhere in `./vendor/somemone/ProjectDependency/Entity/*`.

There are two ways to avoid this:

In `composer.json` don't use universal directory autoloader:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
}
```

and specify my namespace particularly:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "MyProject\\": "src/" }
}
```

With this `orm:generate-entities` will still generate entities in `./src` but these won't be autoloaded so it won't throw class redeclaration error.

Eventually, I can use `--filter` argument:

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-entities --filter="MyProject" ./src
```

and Doctrine2 will generate entity classes only for my `MyProject`.

This made me thinking what is the recommended approach. Maybe idealy combine both?

Answer (score 2):

I think second approach is much preferable approach. Its a better clear and more easy to use method. You should go for the `--filter` option:

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-entities --filter="MyProject" ./src
```